# Is "Preferences" in the context of IA should translate by "Préférences"

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique, mathématiques

I have several colleagues at my lab that work in a field they so call "preferences". Should this term be translated into "préférences" en français ?

[Here is an example of context: automn school in artificial intelligence and preferences](http://ia2.gdria.fr/autumn-school-in-artificial-intelligence/)

Should it be translated: "Ecole d'automne sur l'intelligence articielle et les préférences"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already translated on [that very site](http://ia2.gdria.fr/inscriptions/):

> *Institut d'Automne en Intelligence Artificielle* (thus IA²)
> *Préférences en intelligence artificielle.*